How to connect multi-voltage transceivers in an RS485 bus?
I'm trying to design an ESP32C1-mini mcu based PCB (board 1). This PCB has an RS485 bus interface. As you know this mcu is 3.3V fed. So the transceiver I need should be 3.3V level compliant UART signals.
This PCB1 (in development estatus) will be connected to another existing PCB2 throught via RS485 bus. This existing PCB2 has an SP3085E half duplex transceiver for its UART signals, microcontroller is 5V-fed, so UART signals are it too (see the picture).

I'm going to use the SP3075E device or equivalent (as i.e. THVD1400DR). I was reading the SP3075E (datasheet) and I found the following advertisement:
"The SP3070E - SP3078E devices may not achieve optimal transmit performance if the connected receiver includes a biasing network to 5.0V without a termination resistor. Please see MaxLinear Application Note ANI#21 for further details."
ANI21 details here:

If I get the advertisment it seems to say that using a termination resistor is enough for solving the Vbias discrepance.
I'm wondering how to design bus interface on board1. Because of board2 has no failsafe resistors but it has a capacitor connected to Vcc = 5V (you can see that at the first picture).
If board2 serial port was 3V3, the proposal for board1 design would be something like this:

NOTE: I can't modify board2 side.
Circuit should be low EMI. So I discard digital isolators, as well as NMOS for doing level conversion if Resistor is enough.
So:
1.- How to design the circuit for SP3075E device having into account that the connected device is fed at 5V and the one I'm designing should be 3.3V polarized one? which is the typical way for solving the case?
2.- Maybe should I use another 5V biased transceiver and connect pull up resistors with 3V3 for UART signals side?
3.- Could I consider that having the differential line capacitor connected to the Vcc = 5V is not the same that having biased the line? -And so place an only termination resistor between A and B on my board interface design-

If the problem is finding the appnote, it's first search result on google if you type "maxlinear ani#21". With that appnote, can you answer your own question?

@Justme no, I can't. I tried what you say writing too many ways: ANI21, ANI-21, ANI#21, etc.. Even I went to manufacturer side. But nothing.

If you use the search term as @Justme writes it - not "in many ways" but identically, that app note is the first result on Google.

https://application-notes.digchip.com/094/94-44147.pdf is the link you're after.

@MrGerber I have also found the same you say searching in google before I wrote this post, but link is broken.

Nope. I just downloaded the document using the link I posted above.

@MrGerber thank you, maybe it is a browser issue. I'm unable to start the download from google clicking the first link. But I can do it by clicking your post link. After reading the pdf I noticed it doesn't say anything new: put a resistor and remove the voltage bias from 5 Volts side. I have just edited the post and I added the AN21 comments.


There should be no problem having a 3.3V transceiver on a standard 5V bus. Like the appnote says, the performance may not be optimal "to an unterminated bus with 5V bias resistors". But that's not a problem - you don't seem to have failsafe bias resistors to 5V, and while yout schematics show neither device terminates the bus, you shound anyway terminate it as you would normally do anyway. So, either don't bias to 5V (but biasing to some other voltage is not forbidden) or either don't leave the bus unterminated (and do terminate it).

I don't follow - why would you use a 5V PHY chip but bias it to 3.3V, as you need to supply it with 5V, and then the IO is 5V and you can't generally have 5V PHY with 3.3V MCU that does not tolerate 5V (unless the PHY has separate bus and IO voltages or you do level shifting between 5V and 3.3V with a suitable method (without further defining suitable at this point)).

Yes the capacitors don't bias the line. And proper termination means two termination resistors, one at each end of the bus - which means these devices might not be the two ends of the buses, but if they terminate, they must be at the ends of the bus.



Regard 2nd answer: 5V transceiver is on other board (B2) that will send some serial data to this new board (B1) that I'm designing. The first board uses 5V because of the voltage of the microcontroller, so its UART voltage level is 5V compliant (from transceiver number 2 to its MCU UART pins). The new board (B1) uses an ESP32-C3, but its operation voltage is 3.3V. So I need 3.3 voltage level for TX and RX signals (from transceiver number 1 to the mcu UART unit). Both boards are separated boards connected by RS485 bus.

@Suvi_Eu Yes I did get that part, that's how things are. What I did not get is what is your question and what kind of answer you want for that, because that was very unclear. So I told all options you can do. Using 3.3V PHY with 3.3V MCU is also one of the options.

My question was about manufacturer words regarding the selected 3.3V PHY could not transmit very well to another RS485 unit connected to the bus, if this unit is a 5V PHY device.

@Suvi_Eu I thought that was alread solved by not being an issue if you do what they say. And it wasn't about connecting to a 5V PHY itself, but (1) about a bus with failsafe bias resistors to 5V and then (2) bus not being terminated and (3) you don't seem to have failsafe biasing to 5V at all and (4) it is not a good idea to leave the bus unterminated anyway and it should be terminated. If you terminate bus, the 5V failsafe biasing is not an issue. And it's not an issue as there is no 5V failsafe biasing. Did I now understood what you were asking, or did you mean something else?

thank you for your answer, it has been very usefull. 2nd point was an idea about how to easily pass the UART signals from 5V to 3V3. Pull up Resistors works fine with high impedance states and it's not the case. As you say, a propper way for doing it involves suitable level shifter and I'm trying to avoid this extra circuitry. So I get the app note suggestion about not using biasing resistors, plus the termination resistor. Fortunately the 5V tolerant board hasn't any biasing on its transceiver lines. So I think I can do it that way.
